# Xaml - Font awesome spinner hide/show not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

New to `Xaml` and `WPF`.

I have added a spinner using font-awesome:

```
<fa:ImageAwesome xmlns:fa="http://schemas.fontawesome.io/icons/" x:Name="loading_spinner1" Visibility="Hidden" Icon="Spinner" Spin="True" Height="25" Width="25" Margin="137,360,66,15" Grid.Column="2" />
```

And in my code behind:

```
private void btn_1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //entering
    loading_spinner1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

And for some reason the spinner is not showing.

What am i missing? (If i set the spinner element to visible in the markup its working fine, not working in the code behind)

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer, I was using the main thread, the working code:

```
loading_spinner1.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
{
    loading_spinner1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}));
```